# command not found error in docker images while symlink exsist on that path

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker

I built a docker image for `kubectl` and `aws`, but the aws command fails while the executable is present in the image

```
bash-5.1# aws
bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: No such file or directory
bash-5.1# ls -ltr /usr/local/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            37 Aug  4 12:30 /usr/local/bin/aws -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
```

when I check `$PATH` the directory is part of it

```
bash-5.1# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

The installation is in place and all the files too

```
bash-5.1# aws -h
bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: No such file or directory
bash-5.1# ls -ltr /usr/local/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            37 Aug  4 12:30 /usr/local/bin/aws -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
bash-5.1# ls -ltr /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 Aug  4 12:30 /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws -> ../dist/aws
bash-5.1# ls -ltr /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/a
array.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so  aws                                    aws_completer                          awscli/
bash-5.1# ls -ltr /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       4497192 Aug  4 12:30 /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws
```

but even when I give the absolute path to the aws executable I get error

```
bash-5.1# /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws
bash: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws: No such file or directory
```

I used the `awscli-exe-linux-aarch64-2.2.25.zip` package for awscli2 and this is an `alpine:3.14.0` based image.

Comment: Does the `/usr/local/aws-cli` directory exist in the image as well?  Can you provide a [mcve], for example, your image's Dockerfile?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws` exist? If yes what is the output of command `file /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws`?

Comment: yes it does, added update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was missing glibc for alpine. Had to build it from source to get awscli working.

The error message was quite misleading though tbh.